# How to write a function to handle custom query in JPA repository in spring boot java?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Basically I am hosting a database on server side using spring boot. And I wanted to write custom query from client side which is developed in angular and call a function from server side for giving me the needed results.

The function for server side will look like this:

```
List<rows> func(String customQuery){
  //fetch rows from table using this custom query and return those rows
  //which I can use in client side.
}
Below are examples of customQuery which I need to send from client side:
select * from table;
select * from table where id>10;
select * from table where id>20 and id<30;
```

So far I searched in Internet I could not find any solution. Please help.

Comment: This looks like a huge security breach. How the custom query is retrieved ? A webservice ?

Answer (score 3):

Sending SQL directly from the client would be a complete security failure, because a malicious user could easily figure out how it works and send a `delete from table` to kill your entire app.
Much worse, they might even be able to run `create user ...` to give themselves complete access to your entire database, get sensitive information, install malware, etc.

Instead you'll want to create a REST service in your application with methods such as

```
GET /table
GET /table?minId=10
GET /table?minId=20&maxId=30
```

Return as `application/json` or a similar data format and only return the information your angular app really needs.
Angular would then be responsible for selectively updating the display with your data.

---

Edit:
This is a guide I have found for creating a basic web app based on Spring Boot and Angular. Might be a good starting point for you:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to send **only the parameters** (`minID` and `maxID` in your case) from the client-side and then build the query dynamically on server-side using [Spring JPA Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).